# issue with /usr/src/linux-headers-5.13.0-39-generic/include/linux/vmalloc.h

Tags: 20.04, system-installation

I have two desktops : one UBUNTU 20.04.4 LTS with 5.4.0-107-generic and one XUBUNTU 20.04.4 LTS with 5.13.0-39-generic. Both have x86_64 architecture.
I 've detected a difference between the two [...]/include/linux/vmalloc.h contents.
In 5.13, the declaration of __vmalloc() seems incorrect, as it takes only 2 parameters, and this results in compile error. And in 5.4, the same __vmalloc() takes the requested 3 parameters.
Is that possible that a so-big mistake has been introduced in 5.13? I suspect that the problem is on my side. I should do something wrong, but I've just done the standard installation.
Thank you for your help.
Christian

Comment: Hello. You are comparing apples and oranges. They are 2 different version of Ubuntu so there is bound to be some differences.

Answer (score 0):

The file, as with most files in the kernel tree, changes often. I get 184 lines of output when I `diff` the 2 versions you mention and I see many commits in the kernel source tree between mainline kernels 5.4 and 5.13, and many more since then. I think the answer to your question:

> Is that possible that a so-big mistake has been introduced in 5.13?

Is no.

Comment: Hello, you're probably right. But the point is that I cannot compile  with 5.13 while it's possible with 5.4. For two flavors of UBUNTU at the same release! What should I do? Ask for re-writing the code of the applications so that one is for UBUNTU 20.04 LTS, the other for XUBUNTU 20.04 LTS? Is it possible to have two src kernel releases in one installation and to choose the correct one when compiling?

Comment: Compiling what? If the application your are trying to compile is kernel version dependant, then yes you will have problems.